# putting HTML message into java mail api program

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have the below java program which is used to send mails through java mail api but rite now i have to make sure that the body of the mail should be 
in HTML format below is the HTML message that should be printed in body can you please advise how can i embed this message in my mail body which should be of an HTML type IN THE MAIL. Please advise folks

```
<HTML><BODY></table>Hello,<br><br>Please be advised  following  details<font color=black face="Arial" size=2><br><br><table border=1 
cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0><font color=black face="Arial" size=2><font size=3 face="Arial"><b><tr bgcolor=lightblue><TD nowrap>ABC Reference</TD><TD
nowrap>RTS Reference</TD><TD nowrap>RTYU</TD><TD nowrap>Amount</TD><TD nowrap>Amount</TD><TD nowrap> Amount</TD><TD nowrap>Value
Date</TD><TD nowrap>Remarks</TD></tr></b></font><tr><TD nowrap>315</TD><TD nowrap>IRMAR1</TD><TD nowrap>S</TD><TD nowrap>1,35</TD><TD
nowrap>1352</TD><TD nowrap>0</TD><TD nowrap>13-Apr-2015</TD><TD nowrap></TD></tr><tr><TD nowrap>SM/82970</TD><TD nowrap>IRMAR157</TD><TD
nowrap>AUD</TD><TD nowrap>9,787</TD><TD nowrap>9787</TD><TD nowrap>0</TD><TD nowrap>13-Apr-2015</TD><TD nowrap></TD></tr><tr><TD
nowrap>SM/829705/0315</TD><TD nowrap>IRMAR15</TD><TD nowrap>GBP</TD><TD nowrap>16,968</TD><TD nowrap>16968</TD><TD nowrap>0</TD><TD nowrap>10-Apr-
2015</TD><TD nowrap></TD></tr></font></table><br><br>Please note that this is a system generated email.</table><br><br>For any queries
mail to our group email</table><br><br>Thanks & Regards,<br>ERTY,<br>HFFEREJ,<br>14 3rd RETEY,
Rajasthan, 4540058, India</table><br><br>--------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</BODY></HTML>
```

Below is my program to send tha mails in wgich now instead of text i want to send the html message ..

```
public class abcMailTest {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                String mailSmtpHost = "77.77.77.77";
                String mailSmtpPort = "4321" ;

                 String mailTo = "avdg@abc.com";
                //String mailCc = "avdg@abc.com ";
                String mailFrom = "avdg@abc.com";
                String mailSubject = "sgdtetrtrr";
                String mailText = "Test Mail for mail body "; //**** HTML message of above should come up ****
                sendEmail(mailTo,  mailFrom, mailSubject, mailText, mailSmtpHost ,mailSmtpPort );
            }

            public static void sendEmail(String to,  String from, String subject, String text, String smtpHost , String mailSmtpPort) {
                try {
                    Properties properties = new Properties();
                    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
                    properties.put("mailSmtpPort", mailSmtpPort);

                    //obtaining the session 
                    Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
                    emailSession.setDebug(true);


                    //creating the message
                    Message emailMessage = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
                    emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
                     Address[] cc = new Address[] {
                     new InternetAddress("avdg@abc.com"),
                     new InternetAddress("AER@gmail.com")};
                     emailMessage.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, cc);
                     emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                     emailMessage.setSubject(subject);



                    // Create the message part
                     BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                     messageBodyPart.setContent(text, "text/html");
                     messageBodyPart.setText(text);


                    // Create a multipart message
                     Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                      multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                  // Part two is attachment
                     MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                     String filename = "c:\\abc.pdf";
                     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                     attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                     attachPart.setFileName(filename);

                    multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);

                     // Send the complete message parts
                     emailMessage.setContent(multipart);

                emailSession.setDebug(true);


                    Transport.send(emailMessage);
                }    catch (AddressException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can do this by using `<![CDATA[<html><body>...</body></html>]]>`.

Comment: OO7 request you to please show the changes in above code itself that will help to grasp more easily

Comment: Check out my answer. May it will help you.

Comment: html tags are still there in the message body please

Answer (score 0):

*Try modifying following sample code*. The below is my sample code, you can do this for your HTML format *replacing with your message string*.

```
// Create body of email
String msg = "<![CDATA[<html><body><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h2>Analysis Report</h2>"
                + "<div>The Analysis request for Batch ID:"
                + "<span style='background-color: rgb(206, 249, 216);'>{GROUP NAME}</span>"
                + " submitted on<span style='background-color: rgb(206, 249, 216);'>{SUBMISSION_TIMESTAMP}</span> "
                + "has been processed.</div><div style='margin-top: 10px;'>"
                + "The result was: <br><div style='background-color: rgb(255, 213, 157); "
                + "margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;'>{MESSAGE TEXT}</div></div>"
                + "<div>Please log on to the system to view detailed information.</div>"
                + "</div></body></html>]]>";
msg = msg.replace("{GROUP NAME}", groupName);
msg = msg.replace("{SUBMISSION_TIMESTAMP}", submissionTimestamp);
msg = msg.replace("{MESSAGE TEXT}", messageText);
message.setText(msg, "ISO-8859-1");

message.setHeader("content-Type", "text/html;charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"");
```

**EDIT:**

**My Email Template:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <template id="analysisEmailBodyTemplate">
        <analysisEmailBody>
            <![CDATA[
            <html>
                <body>
                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                        <h2>Analysis Report</h2>
                        <div>
                            The Analysis request for Batch ID:
                            <span style="background-color: rgb(206, 249, 216);">{GROUP NAME}</span> submitted on
                            <span style="background-color: rgb(206, 249, 216);">{SUBMISSION_TIMESTAMP}</span> has been processed.
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px;">The result was: <br>
                            <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 213, 157); margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">{MESSAGE TEXT}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>Please log on to the system to view detailed information.</div>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
            ]]>
        </analysisEmailBody>
    </template>
    <template id="analysisEmailSubjectTemplate">
        <analysisEmailSubject>
            Analysis System results for Batch ID: {GROUP NAME}
        </analysisEmailSubject>
    </template>
</root>
```

**To Parse XML:** Follow [Read XML file in Java – (DOM Parser)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) tutorial to read the value of node whichever you want. Then **set the message read from XML file to `msg` variable**.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: can you please advise what is this GROUP NAME ,UBMISSION_TIMESTAMP,MESSAGE TEXT and ISO-8859-1 please Thanks in advance

Comment: html tags are still there in the message body please

Comment: **This is my configuration, it's specific to my project & doesn't have any relation with ur code. You just have to put your HTML code inside `CDATA`, just like I did**. *For ur info, the values in `{...}` will changes per mail in my case that's why I created `{...}` as constant in message string & change the values for `{GROUP NAME}`, `{SUBMISSION_TIMESTAMP}` & `{MESSAGE TEXT}` dynamically*. I have created an `XML` file & added the above message in it. While sending email, I am parsing XML file to read the message from it & replace the constants from it, will created new email message for me.

Comment: OO7 Thanks can you please advise and also suggest how to create the xml file in my case as i am very eager to send html message please advise

Comment: I have gone through this url also https://bharatonjava.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/sending-email-using-java-mail-api/

Comment: Have u tried my answer ? Did you get solution with this & able to send email ?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling messageBodyPart.setContent followed by MessageBodyPart.setText.  The second call overwrites what the first call did, and switches it back to plain text.

You need to learn how to read the API documentation for JavaMail.  It's a lot faster than posting messages here.  Start with the [MimeBodyPart.setText](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#setText(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.  Replace your two method calls with:

```
messageBodyPart.setText(text, null, "html");
```

Read through all the methods for MimeBodyPart.  You'll find others that are useful as well.